# Row_Number function sorts values involunatrily without order by (Postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, function, sorting, window, row

Hi I have the following data:

[Storage Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9C5nT.png)

And I apply the following query:

```
select row_number() over (partition by "Country", "Product Type") as RN,
"Country", "Product Type", "Process Step", "Volume"
from storage_data;
```

For some odd reason It gives me the following output, where it looks like it partitions by the right variables but it also sorts within Process Step. Could someone explaint that to me please?

[Storage Data Modified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1ech.png)

Comment: If you don't specify an ORDER BY, you can't expect a specific row order. What result were you looking to get?

Comment: In the absence of an ORDER BY, the system can famously process/present the data in any order it find convenient.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `EXPLAIN` output for your query, you will see that PostgreSQL has to sort to calculate `row_number()`, which shouldn't come as a surprise.

Since the query does not contain an `ORDER BY` clause, PostgreSQL returns the rows in the order it calculated them.